# Netsuite: SuiteScript 2.0 - get latest transfer order

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to add lines to a transfer order in Netsuite. I want to add them on the latest order created between two specific locations.

I am trying this:

```
    var s = search.create({
    type : search.Type.TRANSACTION,
    columns : ['internalid'],
    filters : [
              ["location","anyof","61"], 
              "AND", 
              ["transferlocation","anyof","62"], 
              "AND", 
              ["mainline","is","T"], 
              "AND", 
              ["trandate","on","today"]
              ]
        }); 
    
    var resultSet = s.run();
    var latestTO = resultSet[0];
```

But I get this error when I try adding a line to latestTO:

{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":null,"stack":["anonymous(N/recordImpl)","onAction(/SuiteScripts/TEST.js:67)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","details":null,"userEvent":null,"stackTrace"

My script works if I "hardcode" the internalID of the latest transfer order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a Saved Search to access Transfer Orders, you can use `SORT BY` function. You can sort using Date Created in descending order.

[image]

I would suggest you to create the Saved Search and test all your requirements. Later you can export this Saved Search as a script and use it in your code.

In order to get the latest Transfer Order value, you simply need to include InternalID column in your results tab.

```
columns : ['internalid']
```

Later, you'll have to execute this Saved Search using script.

```
var s = search.create({
    type : search.Type.TRANSACTION,
    columns : ['internalid'],
    filters : [
              ["location","anyof","61"], 
              "AND", 
              ["transferlocation","anyof","62"], 
              "AND", 
              ["mainline","is","T"], 
              "AND", 
              ["trandate","on","today"]
              ]
        });


var searchResultCount = s.runPaged().count;
log.debug("s result count",searchResultCount);
s.run().each(function(result){
   // .run().each has a limit of 4,000 results
   return true;
});

var searchResult = s.run().getRange({start:0,end:999});
```

**Variable `searchResultCount` stores the total number of results**

**Variable `searchResult` contains all the data**

In order to get recently created TO, simply fetch the first value.

```
for(var j=0;j<1;j++) {
    var latestTO = searchResult[j].getValue({name:'internalid'});;
}
```

Variable latestTO will now have the internalID. Use this to load the record.

Let me know in case of any issues in the comment section.

Comment: Hi. Yes, my SC is exported already.. but how do I get the highest value after that?

Comment: Working on it, will update this answer.

Comment: Hi, Thank you! I'm not receiving an error, but the line is not added.. Am I doing anything wrong here?         var TO = record.load({
        type: 'transferOrder', 
        id: latestTO,
        isDynamic: true
        });

Comment: Sorry, it did work, but it added the line on the first transfer order created for the day. I guess I will figure it out myself, thank you very much!

Comment: But my another problem, below, is still confusing me. Do you have answer for that too?

Comment: Which problem are you talking about?

Comment: I can not simply define my variable as: var latestTO = '1337' and then use it as                            var TO = record.load({
                            type: 'transferOrder', 
                            id: 1337,
                            isDynamic: true
                            });

Comment: Use FOR LOOP for assigning the value to the variable. I have mentioned the same in my answer.

Comment: Okey, yes and that works. But I was more curious about why it didn't work to assign a variable that day. Thank you big time for your help!

Comment: Reason it didn't worked was this - var resultSet = s.run(); - This ain't the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is if i hardcode my variabel latestTO, as:

var latestTO = '1337';

and make the update:

```
                            var TO = record.load({
                            type: 'transferOrder', 
                            id: latestTO,
                            isDynamic: true
                            });
```

Nothing happens.

But if I do:

```
                            var TO = record.load({
                            type: 'transferOrder', 
                            id: 1337,
                            isDynamic: true
                            });
```

It works...

Comment: Refer to my answer for this